# Update multiple tables with JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, join, subquery, jooq

the problem here with `jooq` is that it doesn't support `join` and `updates`, moreover updates on multiple tables.

I find a way to transform this query:

```
   String query =   "UPDATE knowCRM.customer_did cd ";
        query +=    " LEFT JOIN knowCRM.know_service ks";
        query +=    " ON ks.id = cd.customer_service_id";
        query +=    " LEFT JOIN knowCRM.customer_flags cf";
        query +=    " ON ks.service_owner_id = cf.account_number";
        query +=    " SET cd.is_cli_number= 1, cf.is_cli_number = '0'";
        query +=    " WHERE ks.service_owner_id = " + accountNumber;
        query +=    " AND cd.did_number= " + cliNumber;
```

**into these two:**

```
        int count2 = wrapper.getCreate().update(CUSTOMER_DID)
                        .set(CUSTOMER_DID.IS_CLI_NUMBER, Byte.parseByte("1"))
                        .where(CUSTOMER_DID.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID.equal(
                                    wrapper.getCreate().select(KNOW_SERVICE.ID)
                                    .from(CUSTOMER_FLAGS, KNOW_SERVICE)
                                    .where(KNOW_SERVICE.ID.equal(CUSTOMER_DID.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID))
                                    .and(KNOW_SERVICE.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.equal(CUSTOMER_FLAGS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
                                    .and(KNOW_SERVICE.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.equal(accountNumber))
                                    .and(CUSTOMER_DID.DID_NUMBER.equal(cliNumber))
                                ))
                        .execute();
```

**and**

```
        int count3 = wrapper.getCreate().update(CUSTOMER_FLAGS)
                .set(CUSTOMER_FLAGS.IS_CLI_NUMBER, Byte.parseByte("0"))
                .where(CUSTOMER_FLAGS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER.equal(
                            wrapper.getCreate().select(KNOW_SERVICE.SERVICE_OWNER_ID)
                            .from(CUSTOMER_DID, KNOW_SERVICE)
                            .where(KNOW_SERVICE.ID.equal(CUSTOMER_DID.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID))
                            .and(KNOW_SERVICE.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.equal(CUSTOMER_FLAGS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
                            .and(KNOW_SERVICE.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.equal(accountNumber))
                            .and(CUSTOMER_DID.DID_NUMBER.equal(cliNumber))
                        ))
                .execute();
```

I would like a more clever way to refactor this query with `jooq` whithout having to split it into two massive queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, the `JOIN` operations are specified on an [`org.jooq.Table`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html). There's a pending feature request to add "join convenience methods" also to `UPDATE`, just as they exist also on `SELECT`: [#3266](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3266)

Your original query can be written as such in jOOQ:

```
CustomerDid cd = CUSTOMER_DID.as("cd");
KnowService ks = KNOW_SERVICE.as("ks");
CustomerFlags cf = CUSTOMER_FLAGS.as("cf");

ctx.update(cd.leftJoin(kd)
             .on(ks.ID.eq(cd.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID))
             .leftJoin(cf)
             .on(ks.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.eq(cf.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)))
   .set(cd.IS_CLI_NUMBER, 1)
   .set(cf.IS_CLI_NUMBER, "0")
   .where(ks.SERVICE_OWNER_ID.eq(accountNumber))
   .and(cd.DID_NUMBER.eq(cliNumber))
   .execute();
```

Comment: in case of type mismatch of joining fields use .cast()

Comment: @PedroBorges: This question is about MySQL